# Combo deals for 2 products

Tags: bundled-product, grouped-products

We are looking to implement below requirement. From admin we should be able to create combo offer(Deals) like for example

We have 2 product 
Product 1 - Google Nexus 5 mobile phone - Rs.22500
Product 2 - Nexus 5 Case/Cover - Rs. 1000

Now we need to create a combo offer on above Mobile phone, when user purchase nexus 5 mobile phone its cover should be priced at Rs.500.
This combo deal should be visible to buyer on product detail page of Nexus 4 mobile phone

From admin we should be able to set this deal/combo offers, Logically it should when creating Google nexus 5, there should be a way to select combo product Case/cover and its discounted price which should be displayed on product details page as combo offer.

Please browse below url to and Search for "Frequently Bought Together" section.

http://www.snapdeal.com/product/lenovo-essential-g400s-59383670-touchscreen/955085629

Please let us know any way to achieve above requirement, any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 3):

You could add shopping cart auto discount rules to offer discounts on combo. You would need to add a module that shows combo products on product pages and then rely on discount rules to take care of discounts once a combo is in the cart.